# Why does the RMSE gets worse with my VAR Model

Tags: prediction, var, forecasting, arima, timeserieschart

i have a weekly aggregated data set and i splitted it in 80% Train and 20% Test.
I am performing a one step a head forecast. However as the length becomes larger the performance get really bad. Is that Normal?
The first few steps are predicted okayish.
[Plot Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x2ih.png)

Comment: Can you please add source code so we can check how you create your model and perform forecasts?

Comment: results = model.fit (10)3lagged_Values = var_test.values

Comment: Can you add the full code to your question, please? E.g., it's always helpful if we can see the classes your are using.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey it really isnt about the code i was just wondering if this is a valid out come if the VAR Modell is good for the first 20 steps (weekly data) and then gets worse after 40 steps till the end of the Testset.
I am doing a multistep forecast.

Comment: How many steps do you forecast into the future? Do you try to forecast the whole year at once?

Comment: @ArneDecker yes i forecast the whole year 65 steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like normal behavior. The forecasts of your model are based on the last observations of your time series. Let us say as an example, the forecast for October 1st is based on the values from September. Now, for October 1st you have 30 correct values from September. Depending on how good your model is, the prediction will deviate a little bit from the true value. When you predict October 2nd, you use 29 correct values from September and the previously predicted value for October 1st. This is called dynamic forecasting. The forecasting error from this prediction is now fed into the model, which impacts the quality of the forecast for October 2nd. If you predict October 3rd, you have 28 correct input values and already two with a slight deviation.

The values for November will be based on forecasts entirely and all forecasting errors in October are fed into the model. Your predictions for July are based on predictions that were based on predictions and so on. Therefore, the predictions get worse and worse the further you forecast into the future and at some points they tend to converge into a straight line.

For this reason, you cannot really predict that far into the future very often. 65 steps is very far into the future and I guess that is too much for ARIMA/VAR.

Comment: I see that makes sense.
So does it make sense to look at the RMSE at lower steps? The Graph will be the same but only short time considered?
So for example if i compare VAR and ARIMA at 20 steps forecast and at 65 steps would that make sense to tell which Modell is better for short or long term forecast?

Comment: It is hard to say that in general without knowing your model. A forecast 65 time steps into the future is probably nor reliable in both models. Looking on the plot I would guess you can compare the performance of the model for 5 to 10 steps, after that it deviates too much.

Comment: I see but the generell approach to compare them 5 steps, 10 steps and so on for mutli step forecasting without reestimation is correct?
And really much thanks for your help !

Comment: Just to be sure, you are creating a multistep forecast for 5, 10, ...  and 65 steps all at once without any retraining/updating the model right?

Comment: correct, to see which model performs the best with this task.

Comment: Okay. You can create multistep forecasts and compare them of course, however I still think that anything your model does beyond ~10 steps into the future is more random then generalized information.

Comment: Yes right just wanted to know if that make sense.
Cause i am comparing SARIMAX VAR LSTM GRU with different aggreagtion (daily, weekly, monthly) an then do a multistepforecast on the test whole test set (20%).
After that i look at the RMSE/MAE at steps 2, half testset and whole testset.